# Are "No more healthy than" and "No more big than" both OK?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, negation, comparatives, comparisons

I am Japanese and a teacher of English. Now I am at a loss at a topic on "Comparison."

This sentence should be considered grammatically OK:

> Oversleeping is no more healthy than overeating.

Whereas this sentence seems to be deemed wrong (including by AI-based grammar checkers):

> This camera is no more big than my hands.

However, it does not make sense to me as these sentences should be identical in terms of their syntax and grammar.

Are both sentences correct?

Comment: Both sentences in the question are fine as written.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica False. You are no more big than a grasshopper leaps.

Comment: So, "no more big than" is okay as well? How come "more big" is allowed here then....
Usually it is 100% wrong to use that form instead of bigger. ><

Comment: @Kyozy No, *more big* is always wrong, just like *more good* and *more bad*.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then can we take more- comparative for two-syllable adjectives ending in y such as healthy or sexy?

Comment: You can use _more big_ when you are comparing the qualities of a single item rather than two items. For example: _The car's more big than good_. Or _He's more lazy than stupid_. You can't say *_The car's bigger than good_ or *_He's lazier than stupid_.  See here: https://books.google.de/books?id=vIy7eEqEqKkC&pg=PA121&lpg=PA121&dq=%22more+big+than%22&source=bl&ots=iCuQ0reJXW&sig=ACfU3U12Ued5WNh8BgBTuAwoFXVBCbyF6Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjtppCBjd_lAhVRyKQKHXO-AIE4ChDoATADegQIBhAB#v=onepage&q=%22more%20big%20than%22&f=false

Comment: Some words have comparative forms, like, big - bigger - biggest; healthy, healthier, healthiest, unlike words like, beautiful, troublesome, derogatory which can become comparatives like more beautiful, most beautiful; more troublesome, most troublesome, more derogatory, most derogatory etc. It's because they don't have comparative forms.

Comment: [Related questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/negation%2bcomparatives?tab=Votes).

Comment: Your first sentence contains "healthy" for which there are two alternative comparisons - "more healthy" and "healthier". You could have said "Oversleeping is no healthier than overeating". That would have provided a parallel with "This camera is no bigger than my hand".

Comment: @Kyozy , the **overwhelming issue** nobody is mentioning is that the phrase "no more than.." (and similar phrases, particularly "no worse than") is ***only used*** in the sense of making a negative, disagree-ing, sarcastic answer to a usually rhetorical question.  Statements that the sentences are or are not "grammatically correct" are utterly useless here and completely miss the point.  You tell me "I can't believe you trust CNN?" {in the example, say you're a known SO user); my response "You're joking, it's no worse than stackoverflow."

Comment: one small point, @shoe that's a side issue that is so far on the side it is about 20 web sites away. It does not help, adding confusion on confusion in a QA like this which is "all confusion".

Comment: This camera is not bigger than my hands: big, bigger, biggest. And: X is no more healthy than eating. **is not a comparative**. idiomatic expression: to be no more [some thing] than x. I am no more Japanese than my brother. :)

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica - both sentences are fine as written, in that, utterly unintelligible sentences (which are indeed totally mangled common idioms, as opposed to just random mangled unintelligible sentences), which are theoretically grammatically correct, are fine!

Answer (score 19):

Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik have the following in their *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (pp. 462-463):

> Most adjectives that are inflected for their comparison can also take the periphrastic forms with *more* and *most*.  With *more*, they seem to do so more easily when they are predicative and are followed by a *than*-clause:
>
> - John is *more mad* than Bob is.
> - It would be difficult to find a man *more brave* than he is.
> - He is *more wealthy* than I thought.
>
> Periphrastic forms are, however, uncommon with a number of monosyllabic adjectives (including those listed in 7.75 as forming their comparison irregularly [good, bad, far]):
>
> *bad, big, black, clean, fair* [colour], *far, fast, good, great, hard, high, low, old, quick, small, thick, thin, tight, wide, young*

They add the following note:

> There seem to be fewer restrictions on using the periphrastic forms with adjectives in the comparative construction formed with the correlative *the...the*:
>
> - The *more old/older* we are, the *more wise/wiser* we become.
>
> BUT NOT: *a more old man
>
> *Good* and *bad*, however, require nonperiphrastic forms (*better*, *worse*) even here.

The example you give fits the context in which fewer restrictions seem to apply to the use of the periphrastic form only partially.  *Big* is used predicatively and followed by *than*, though not by a *than*-clause.  Perhaps the addition of *are* could make it more acceptable:

- This camera is no more big than my hands are.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your answer!
That was pretty understandable explanation to me!

Comment: There are plenty of idiomatic constructions with *more big*, but they depend on context, as in a dialog: “Were their players more talented?”   “No, just more big.” (said in a tone of disgust).

Comment: Quirk et al don't address the 'no more Adj[absolute-form]'  string; even the negator may skew preferred choice (padding often affords more licence). And of course there are strings (with absolute-class adjectives or nouns) not possible without 'no': "He is no more dead than I am." "He is no more mad than Bob is" has a different meaning from "He is no madder than Bob is."

Answer (score 15):

Instead of using *more* to form comparatives, notice what happens when you use inflection for the comparative degree:

1. Oversleeping is **no healthier than** overeating.
2. The camera is **no bigger than** my hands.

*More big* is always wrong to form the comparative degree, which is always *bigger* .

*More healthy* could also be *healthier* but it does not necessarily need to be.

Comment: "More big" isn't technically wrong, it's just not idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks Sure it is, but if you disagree, please post a more good answer; it can hardly be more bad.

Comment: I sure you would consider it worser.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers.

Comment: I am currently more confused about this.
I thought that two-syllable adjectives ending in-y always take comparative and superlative forms of -er -est....

Comment: I was taught *more big* is grammatically wrong. "*big, bigger, biggest*", not "*big, more big, most big*"... ...

Comment: So then how come we always say "You couldn't be more wrong" and never "You couldn't be wronger"?

Comment: @Robusto wronger *than*...?

Comment: @Jalene Nearly all  "grammar rules" that get spouted about XYZ being wrong are wrong.  Why? They only exist if people say XYZ,

Comment: @HotLicks  If it isn't idiomatic, then it isn't English. Ergo, it's 'wrong' English. We, the people, have decided.

Comment: "There are more big apples on this tree" and "There are bigger apples on this tree" are both idiomatic English, but they mean different things.

Comment: But TC.  "Oversleeping is no healthier than overeating" is unbelievably confusing because the latter concept is an ***un-*** healthy one.  *It's like saying x is no bluer than a desk*  x is no bluer than the ocean is meaningful;  x is no bluer than a desk is nonsense, or goon-show playfulness at best.

Comment: "There are more big apples on this tree" could be perceived in two ways though and is confusing.  Are there more apples that could be considered big, or are the apples actually larger?

Comment: @Josh No, that is not ambiguous at all. Because the comparative degree of *big* is *bigger*, there is only one possible reading of your sentence.

Comment: It is useful to mention for didactic purposes that nouns with three or more syllables do form the comparative with more. For someone teaching that is important: He skies more frequently than I do.

Comment: @Lambie I hope this won’t be the ***unhappiest*** thing you hear all day, but it turns out that **nouns** don't form compative degrees at all. Only adjectives and adverbs do so. And trisyllablic adjectives like *unhappy* do form, or at least can form inflected comparatives and superlatives via inflection not via periphrasis with *more* and *most*.

Comment: ^Yes, I meant to say adjectives. When one goes fast, as I do, one often has writing lapsae.

Answer (score 1):

I think the construction "X is no more A than Y" normally functions idiomatically to express "X is not A." You are saying some predicate does not apply in this case, just as it doesn't apply in this other case. The tacit part of the expression is "...Y is A." See below:

> - "Oversleeping is no more healthy than overeating (is healthy)."
> - "This camera is no more big than my hands (are big)."

It's not that the camera sentence is ungrammatical; it's just that it looks like it doesn't say what it intends to, which is that the camera is about hand-sized.

Here's a case where "no more big" would go through:

> Child1: I'm big!
> Parent: You're not big.
> Child2: I'm big!
> Parent: You're no more big than Child1.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> Oversleeping is no more healthy than overeating.

.

> This camera is no more big than my hands.

In native English, these two sentences are incredibly uncomfortable, in a word they are **wrong**.

(The fact that they may or may not be grammatically correct is a naive path of enquiry. This sentence not not the other not not sentence is 'grammatically correct', and that fact is of no value.)

The remarkably obvious, common way to state the first type of thought is:

> Oversleeping is just as bad as overeating.

**"... is just as bad as ..."** is a very common formulation in English rhetorical exchanges, and, in this setting (which is an exact example of it), anything else sounds weird.

For the second one,

> This camera is no bigger than my hands.

Ditto on that formulation.  The incorrect sentence is so close to a common phrase, yes so incorrect, that it sounds very incorrect. Indeed, it's a perfect example of "humorous foreign English" where one fluffs a common phrase.

Further, note that a similar-sounding common formulation in a certain type of argument is ***".. no worse than .."*** where you are "throwing back in the other person's face" some relevant negative point.

You tell me "You shouldn't smoke so muchy, smoking is bad"; my response "It's no worse than alcohol!" (In the example, the first party drinks a lot.)

The first given incorrect sentence is particularly bad because ***it sounds like one is trying to use that formulation***, but has everfthing messed up on a couple of levels. To wit, it sounds like the speaker has confused a use case of the "just as bad as" formulation with a use case of the "well that's no worse than" formulation.  (And, additionally, messed-up the words anyway.)

Comment: This answer looks more of opinion than informed English. Even equating something unusual to be wrong is not proper use of linguistics. And this site is about English linguistics, not English opinion. You may want to edit your answer to provide references and published examples/definitions.

Comment: Ola @PabloStraub , this is an unusual site.  Most of the questions, say 80%, are essentially asking: "in Native natural English, what is _ _ _".  Just as the OED is a book of opinion, as explained in the famous intro to the first edition ("we believe the most common spelling in the wild of XYZ is such and such") The whole site is just opinion, and can only be.  Often, folks try to reach for "proof" by using Google Books as a corpus - but that's just written.  Many, many questions, such as this one, are about figures of speech, and their correct or (such as here) incorrect usage.

Comment: I observe you're trying to go through the site and on every answer add a comment that the answer is opinion  :)  That is a big task  :)

Comment: I suggest too @PabloStraub that this site famously has some remarkably "off on a tangent" QA.  Simply looking at the question here, which should be closed anyway, the overwhelming thing to point out is that ***it is a mangled common idiom***.  That's the elephant in the room. Everything else is a sideshow.

Comment: And finally!  You mention "this site is about English linguistics", apparently it is not. Help center -> "Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: Word choice and usage .."  (I believe there's actually another site for linguistics?)  Also, as far as I understand it, academically "linguistics" usually means looking in to form, meaning, usage (ie, my answer here), not really "grammar 'rules'" as such.  These are all weighty issues. In general a blanket "sources.." doesn't really work here, I fear. (Unless it's just a school "grammar question", which shouldn't be on the site anyways.)

Answer (score -1):

> John is more mad than Bob is.
>   It would be difficult to find a man more brave than he is.

Why do we have the sentence terminating with an is?
As I learned in school, we would put the is before the noun, or omit it completely

> John is more mad than is Bob. or John is more mad than Bob.

It would be difficult to find a man more brave than he.

Comment: Hi @Leslie. Welcome to English Language & Usage. A text like yours is better to appear in a comment than in an answer. The expectation for answers are well-researched, informative texts that directly address the question asked.